# React Native Expo app crashes only (!) in Testflight, but not on Expo Development Server and only when navigating with certain params

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation, testflight

I'm trying to create my first React Native App using Expo and am currently stuck at a problem that only occurs on the Apple Testflight App, not in normal development mode (when executing the app on Expo Server).

In my app, there are different ToDos with different Ids. The ToDos are stored in a Firebase Database and the IDs are assigned randomly by the database (when creating a new ToDo).

The Error (or the Crash) occurs when executing the navigation.navigate() function of the npm package react-navigation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/ ).
This method takes the name of a Screen (as String) and it's possible to add additional parameters. To create a new (empty) ToDo, I navigate to my *ToDoDetailScreen* with todoId 0. This works fine, both in Expo Development Mode and on the Testflight App.

```
<ButtonC onPress={() => { navigation.navigate(PR_TODO_DETAIL_SCREEN, { todoId: 0 }) }} />
```

However, when I want to navigate to an already existing ToDo (with a different ID, for example like "2issHSpPo1IQtAElg6w5") it works just fine on my Expo development server, but in the Testflight App it crashes. The executing call code is this:

```
<Button onPress={() => { navigation.navigate(PR_TODO_DETAIL_SCREEN, { todoId: item.id }) }}/>
```

(That I use ButtonC and the second time button is intended and should not cause any problems since both calls work in the development mode). The constant PR_TODO_DETAIL_SCREEN just is the corresponding name (String) of my Screen:

```
export const PR_TODO_DETAIL_SCREEN = 'ToDoDetailScreen';
```

I can look into some Crash Reports provided by the Testflight App, but I'm developing on a Windows System with Expo and do not use XCode. So I'm not very familiar to the kind of crash log I obtained and can't find anything specific online too. The crashlog.crash file looks like this when I open it using a text editor:

```
Incident Identifier: 891953D5-ED10-4118-A060-85DA007F02CD
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,2
Process:             timetool [38661]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CADBEA3E-8594-4022-8065-AA055C1D641F/timetool.app/timetool
Identifier:          com.janoschvk.timetool
Version:             1.0.0 (3)
AppStoreTools:       13E500
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,2:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.janoschvk.timetool [1327]

Date/Time:           2022-05-04 12:18:42.7630 +0200
Launch Time:         2022-05-04 11:51:03.1271 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.4.1 (19E258)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.03.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  1

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1b853dd78 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1d11a2734 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   timetool                        0x104ab83e0 RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:146)
3   timetool                        0x104b35a00 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:suppressRedBox:] + 600 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:89)
4   timetool                        0x104b363bc -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1532 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:164)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1b84c6614 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1b84e4100 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 468 (NSForwarding.m:3378)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1b851b13c -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:3475)
8   timetool                        0x104ae91e4 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   timetool                        0x104aeb67c facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 540 (RCTNativeModule.mm:181)
10  timetool                        0x104aeb2b4 operator() + 56 (RCTNativeModule.mm:103)
11  timetool                        0x104aeb2b4 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 100 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b81a2e68 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b81a4a2c _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b81ac124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (inline_internal.h:2622)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b81acc80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392 (queue.c:3944)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1b81b7500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2294c20bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2294c1e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d119b020 bool objc::DenseMapBase<objc::DenseMap<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::ObjcAssociation>, objc::DenseMapInfo<void const*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<void const*, o... + 144 (llvm-DenseMap.h:671)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d1193770 objc_setAssociatedObject + 868 (llvm-DenseMap.h:701)
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001baaf3b94 -[UIView _addGeometryChangeObserver:] + 124 (UIView.m:8759)
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001baaf3c08 -[UIView _addGeometryChangeObserver:] + 240 (UIView.m:8803)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bac03ad0 -[_UITAMICAdaptorView didMoveToWindow] + 84 (_UITAMICAdaptorView.m:100)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001babcbae4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 2240 (UIView.m:16061)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001baaf1ef4 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 140 (UIView.m:12349)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab815b8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 812 (UIView.m:476)
8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001baa9e258 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2152 (UIView.m:16778)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bae14720 -[_UILayoutArrangement insertItem:atIndex:] + 468 (_UILayoutArrangement.m:489)
10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bad0a7f4 __50-[_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement insertItem:atIndex:]_block_invoke + 52 (_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement.m:213)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bad668d4 -[_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement _trackChangesAffectingExternalBaselineConstraints:] + 156 (_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement.m:183)
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bacd8264 -[_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement insertItem:atIndex:] + 496 (_UIOrderedLayoutArrangement.m:212)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bae53a44 -[UIStackView insertArrangedSubview:atIndex:] + 264 (UIStackView.m:107)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bad069e0 -[_UIButtonBar _layoutBar] + 2576 (UIButtonBar.m:555)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab456b4 __42-[_UIButtonBarStackView updateConstraints]_block_invoke + 52 (UIButtonBar.m:1284)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001baa87054 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104 (UIView.m:14609)
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab76f60 -[_UIButtonBarStackView updateConstraints] + 120 (UIButtonBar.m:1283)
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bac8e210 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 484 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:0)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001baaa3ca8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 1000 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4415)
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001baaa3b88 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 712 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4396)
21  CoreAutoLayout                  0x00000001d14a55c4 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 88 (NSISEngine.m:1988)
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab0b798 __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 112 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4461)
23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab3db10 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 128 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4161)
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab86cb0 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 188 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4460)
25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bad9b898 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 536 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4735)
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab0473c -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 912 (UIView.m:12823)
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001baddd178 -[_UINavigationBarTransitionContextPush _prepareContentView] + 228 (_UINavigationBarTransitionContext.m:1060)
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bad98728 -[_UINavigationBarTransitionContextPush prepare] + 104 (_UINavigationBarTransitionContext.m:1201)
29  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bad7ad30 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _performAnimationWithTransitionCompletion:transition:] + 2280 (_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS.m:1818)
30  UIKitCore                       0x00000001babc7cb0 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItem:transitionAssistant:] + 604 (UINavigationBar.m:1926)
31  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bae1acec -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItemUsingCurrentTransition:] + 340 (UINavigationBar.m:1770)
32  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bacb351c -[UINavigationBar pushNavigationItem:animated:] + 200 (UINavigationBar.m:1802)
33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bac86bf8 -[UINavigationBar _performUpdatesIgnoringLock:] + 68 (UINavigationBar.m:351)
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab8c448 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItem:transition:] + 160 (UINavigationBar.m:1813)
35  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bab867ac __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke + 448 (UINavigationController.m:8306)
36  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bb228548 __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke.2160 + 124 (UINavigationController.m:8360)
37  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bac28ffc __98-[UINavigationController _shouldSkipHostedRefreshControlUpdateSchedulingDeferredUpdateIfNecessary]_block_invoke + 36 (UINavigationController.m:7175)
38  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bade9be0 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1308 (UINavigationController.m:7567)
39  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bacbf140 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 168 (UINavigationController.m:7835)
40  UIKitCore                       0x00000001babe6b38 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 228 (UILayoutContainerView.m:88)
41  UIKitCore                       0x00000001baaa0844 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2592 (UIView.m:18426)
42  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc2161c0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 532 (CALayer.mm:10116)
43  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc2085fc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136 (CALayer.mm:2479)
44  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc21cf70 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 452 (CAContextInternal.mm:2612)
45  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc225e78 CA::Transaction::commit() + 704 (CATransactionInternal.mm:449)
46  QuartzCore                      0x00000001bc207d7c CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 88 (CATransactionInternal.mm:956)
47  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84e5bb4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36 (CFRunLoop.c:1804)
48  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84b4b70 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 592 (CFRunLoop.c:1917)
49  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84afc2c __CFRunLoopRun + 1052 (CFRunLoop.c:2979)
50  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84c36b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
51  GraphicsServices                0x00000001d455d374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
52  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bae28e88 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
53  UIKitCore                       0x00000001babaa5ec UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
54  timetool                        0x00000001049f3c68 main + 88 (main.m:7)
55  dyld                            0x0000000105121ce4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efeacb78 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c83bc pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1668)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001c362051c abort + 168 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001d12adb7c abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001d129d9c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 336 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:71)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d11a8c88 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001d12acf18 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001d12aceb4 std::terminate() + 64 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b81a4a40 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b81ac124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668 (inline_internal.h:2622)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b81acc80 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392 (queue.c:3944)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b81b7500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648 (queue.c:6732)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c20bc _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2599)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea64e0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6b24 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84ab820 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84afcac __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84c36b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001b9caa414 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b9cebcac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bada2fb0 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001b9cfa55c __NSThread__start__ + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea64e0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6b24 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84ab820 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84afcac __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84c36b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   timetool                        0x0000000104acac64 +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 264 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:308)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b9cfa55c __NSThread__start__ + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea64e0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6b24 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84ab820 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84afcac __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b84c36b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001b8f394d8 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 472 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001b9cfa55c __NSThread__start__ + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6f64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c9298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c49264d4 scavenger_thread_main + 1232 (pas_scavenger.c:131)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6f64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c9298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48885f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c472bcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c484f594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48a8f68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48ab274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6f64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c9298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48885f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c472bcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c484f594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48a8f68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48ab274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6f64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c9298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48885f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c472bcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c484f594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48a8f68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48ab274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6f64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c9298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48885f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c472bcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c484f594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48a8f68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48ab274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6f64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c9298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48885f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c472bcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c484f594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48a8f68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48ab274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 14 name:
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001efea6f64 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c9298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48885f4 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 1844 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:622)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c472bcd0 bool WTF::Condition::waitUntilUnchecked<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 248 (ParkingLot.h:82)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c484f594 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::AbstractLocker const&)::$_0, void>::call() + 260 (Condition.h:77)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48a8f68 WTF::Thread::entryPoint(WTF::Thread::NewThreadContext*) + 352 (Function.h:82)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001c48ab274 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 16 (ThreadingPOSIX.cpp:242)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c29ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002294c1e54 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001d12b10f5   x5: 0x000000016b526430   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000700
    x8: 0x0fb6381b75daf9c5   x9: 0x0fb6381a1e8889c5  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x00000001b887aaff  x14: 0x00000001d12b111b  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016b527000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000002903  x21: 0x000000016b5270e0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000016b5270e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000028161f8e8  x26: 0x0000000000000114  x27: 0x0000000282d34a40
   x28: 0x0000000282d34a40   fp: 0x000000016b5263a0   lr: 0x00000002294c83bc
    sp: 0x000000016b526380   pc: 0x00000001efeacb78 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
0x1049ec000 - 0x104c6ffff timetool arm64  <5621399c0cb336c0a7af4d56989005e7> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/CADBEA3E-8594-4022-8065-AA055C1D641F/timetool.app/timetool
0x105108000 - 0x10515ffff dyld arm64e  <d16b72c0d6193e4892622c10a1d3066f> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1b81a1000 - 0x1b81e6fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <69dac9c7ddaf318eb068be596d142a2f> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1b84a4000 - 0x1b88f9fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <d2716f2f688b3d51ba8b17e6553b209e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1b8cc2000 - 0x1b9182fff CFNetwork arm64e  <eae64611a84036fea69d5658f1bcf4d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1b9c92000 - 0x1b9f9afff Foundation arm64e  <feeef9b1b0e63561adfa3ef0302d23f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1ba915000 - 0x1bc1affff UIKitCore arm64e  <e6e89bb5b5863725bf8f4c85dcd443bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1bc1d6000 - 0x1bc4e5fff QuartzCore arm64e  <a491ae8b354b35c1ab22af42a96b6704> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x1c3600000 - 0x1c367ffff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <b0793d31ed1b3549b86192a10841bf68> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1c36d8000 - 0x1c4a4dfff JavaScriptCore arm64e  <6592b928ee2c3bc2b4e94cdc77022fe0> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1d118c000 - 0x1d11c8fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <a196a0f6cadb325bbc1f5965e670f9b6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1d129c000 - 0x1d12b3fff libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <fe24cee611ec3951aa1832594f98ef0d> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1d149d000 - 0x1d14e7fff CoreAutoLayout arm64e  <8d1c126529123d349abb61ab3e116ea5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAutoLayout.framework/CoreAutoLayout
0x1d455c000 - 0x1d4564fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <75a910dc87a43b3a8c0ea868b945f5d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1efea5000 - 0x1efedafff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <c2fcc05874803c14b4790064a3f843e3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x2294c1000 - 0x2294ccfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <b48efcbed4f7308ba3fa172e0ea78e33> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF
```

Versions:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1 
react-native: 0.64.3 
expo --version: 5.4.3 
react-navigation: 7.21.0

Has anyone encountered similar problems like this or got another idea where the error could be ? I don't know how to debug any further and would appreciate every help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by now. A little bit embarassing, but the problem was just based on somewhat access rights. In the client, in my app I forget to make sure, that only items are loaded with the corresponding userId to the logged in user. In my firebase database, I created a security rule to make sure that only items could be loaded with the specific user Id. Also when opening one item, there was an additional check on the client side for that userId. The serverside security rule or the double checking client security rule leaded to the crash of the app. So please be sure to check your access rules on data for inconsistencies if you encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the expo app in production mode with expo start --no-dev --minify [here are the expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/development-mode/). To me, it seems that item.id is undefined or null and if you are populating the screen with the item information is causing the crash.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a good tip because I did not know about these production mode before, but the error is still not occuring in production mode...
I think I'm going to have a look at other ways of debugging in the Apple Testflight App

Comment: Great tip. This caused my app to also crash in the `Expo Go` app, which enabled me to test without doing a rebuild for every change.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I was missing was:

```
npm install expo-modules-core
npm install expo-contants
```

I think it's pretty poor the way the eas upgrade works, if I'm honest. The original expo build worked well.

I have also done a shed-load of other dependencies, so the above on its own may not help you.

Comment: How did you know?

Comment: I ejected the project and tried to load into xcode. The error messages pointed to the libraries above

Comment: I assume this is `expo-constants` not `expo-contants`?

Comment: Yes it wont let me change answer